# iText Add watermarking text vertically along the left hand side border center aligned

Tags: pdf, itext, pdf-generation, watermark

I need to add a water marking text vertically along the left hand side border of the PDF document. The watermark text should be center aligned as well. I checked several examples from iText but could not get this done yet. Any help is appreciated.[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hMbB.png) http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/miscellaneous/vertical-text

Comment: The link to the documentation that you share is about vertical text. I don't see how that would be relevant. You want to add a [Watermark](http://developers.itextpdf.com/search/node/Watermark) containing [rotated text](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-rotate-single-line-text). I guess the 3 close votes and 2 down votes are caused by the fact that you didn't show what you've tried and that you linked to an unrelated page on the official web site as an excuse so that you can say "I've looked at the documentation". Is that correct? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that your question already received 3 close votes with as reason "unclear what you're asking". Allow me to explain what is unclear first, then I'll try to solve the problem.

It is unclear if you are creating a document from scratch or if you want to add a watermark to an existing document:

- If you're creating a document from scratch, you need to use *page events* to add the watermark to every page automatically. This means that you'll have to look in the [page events](http://developers.itextpdf.com/faq/category/page-events) section of the documentation. If you didn't know about page events, you probably would have ended up there anyway, by searching for the key word [Watermark](http://developers.itextpdf.com/search/node/Watermark), where you'd find answers to questions such as [How to add text as a header or footer?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-text-header-or-footer)
- If you want to add the watermark to an existing document, you need to use `PdfStamper`, a class that is used in many answers to the questions in the section [Manipulating existing PDFs](http://developers.itextpdf.com/faq/category/manipulating-existing-pdfs) of the official documentation.

You are confusing people by referring to an example about [Vertical text](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/miscellaneous/vertical-text), which is meant to explain how iText supports vertical writing systems, such as for instance the writing system for Japanese where glyphs are written in vertical columns. Seeing the down-votes you received, I think that causing this confusion annoyed the down-voters in the sense that they probably thought you just linked to the first, random example you found so that you had an excuse in case they asked you "what have you tried?"

Now for the solution. It is unclear to me if you want to add a watermark to a document created from scratch or to an existing document. Let's assume you want to add a watermark to an existing document. In that case, you need the [WatermarkToTheSide](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/stamping-content-existing-pdfs/watermark-examples#1677-watermarktotheside.java) example:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    PdfContentByte canvas;
    Rectangle pageSize;
    float x, y;
    for (int p = 1; p <= n; p++) {
        pageSize = reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(p);
        // left of the page
        x = pageSize.getLeft();
        // middle of the height
        y = (pageSize.getTop() + pageSize.getBottom()) / 2;
        // getting the canvas covering the existing content
        canvas = stamper.getOverContent(p);
        // adding some lines to the left
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
            new Phrase("This is some extra text added to the left of the page"),
            x + 18, y, 90);
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
            new Phrase("This is some more text added to the left of the page"),
            x + 34, y, 90);
    }
    stamper.close();
}
```

Note that I took a pretty special PDF to test this on: [pages.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/resources/pdfs/pages.pdf)

This PDF has pages with a different size, different orientation, and so on. When you look at the result, you see that one page doesn't seem to have a watermark: [side_watermark.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/stamper/cmp_side_watermark.pdf)

You might think that the watermark is missing on page 5. It isn't! It is there, but it is invisbile because it was added outside the CropBox. You might want to adapt my example so that it also takes into account the existence of a CropBox.

Suppose that I made the wrong assumption, suppose that your question was about creating documents from scratch. In that case, your question is a duplicate of [How to add text as a header or footer?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-text-header-or-footer)

The only difference with a header and a footer, lies in the position of the text. You just need to replace the two `showTextAligned()` lines in the header/footer example with the lines I've used in the [WatermarkToTheSide](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/stamping-content-existing-pdfs/watermark-examples#1677-watermarktotheside.java) example:

```
ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
    new Phrase("This is some extra text added to the left of the page"),
    x + 18, y, 90);
ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
    new Phrase("This is some more text added to the left of the page"),
    x + 34, y, 90);
```

If your document was created with an A4 page size, `x` can be replaced by `0` and `y` can be replaced by `421` (which is half the height of an A4 page).

Comment: This is really cool. This is exactly what I was asking for. Thanks a lot. :)